# How to make this existing code auto play photo slideshow?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

This is the existing code for a website photo slideshow with left/right arrows. I would l like to add to or fix this code so it will auto play the slides every .7s, while still keeping the ability for the visitor to use the arrows. I am very new at this and it is probably awful coding but I am not having success with anything I have tried. Please help!

```css
#slider {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  /*width:994px; */
  height: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #5c90db;
  postion: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}


/*slides-this is the main content area split into two columns*/

div.columns {
  width: 994px;
}

div.columns div {
  width: 497px;
  height: 560px;
  float: left;
}

div.right {
  background-color: #ECE6E6;
}

div.left {
  background-color: #ECE6E6;
}

div.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.slides {
  padding: 0;
  /*border:1px #000 solid;*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slider01.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: tons of examples online. try some and return with specific questions.

Comment: I see the examples online, I am trying to add code to this one so it will work. Is it unreasonable to expect that a few lines of code can be added to it, or is there much more to it than that?

Comment: From what i can tell it will take a fair bit more, but I'm not looking into it in detail. Do you have to figure it out from scratch? There are code samples online but there are also libraries that do it without writing much code at all.

Comment: Ok, so since it seems it will take a lot more to make this code work to automatically slide from one image to the next, does anyone know of a good online code generator where I can at least start with clean code and modify it? Looking for photos to auto transition with fade, and also arrows.